# jquery show/hide integrated with toggle/accordion effect

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a show/hide toggle working well in multiple instances (thanks to help here - search for 'jquery toggle to work in multiple instances').

I want to integrate it into an expanding menu / accordion style for the main categories.
I have a script and it works on its own but I can't get it to work integrated with the show/hide.

The working show/hide:
http://pastebin.me/c69869d7a80fdb439ca16304b821c146

the expanding menu script I want to integrate:
http://pastebin.me/03b685f586fef84193b5fd72e815255d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure *exactly* what you're after, so this is a bit of a guess and a quick rought cut, needs optimization, but should work:

```
jQuery.fn.expandingMenu = function(options) {
   settings = jQuery.extend({
     speed: 500,
     show: 10,
     hideCaption: 'Hide',
     showCaption: 'More'
  }, options);

  if (this.children('.active').length) return this;

  this.each(function() {
    if ($(this).children().slice(settings.show).hide().length) {
       $(this).append($('<li class="toggler">' + settings.showCaption + '</li>').toggle(function() {
          $(this).text(settings.hideCaption).siblings().slideDown(settings.speed);
       }, function() { 
          $(this).text(settings.showCaption).siblings().slice(settings.show + 1).slideUp(settings.speed);
       }));
    }

    $(this).children().hide().first().show().css({cursor:"pointer"}).toggle(function () { 
      $(this).siblings().slice(0, settings.show).add($(this).siblings('.toggler')).show(settings.speed);
    }, function () {
        $(this).siblings().hide(settings.speed);
    });
  });
  return this;
};

$(function() {
    $('ul').expandingMenu({ speed: 200, showCaption: "Gimme More" });     
});
```

[See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/HnLQF/4/).  This example makes it a plugin model, so you can call `$('ul').expandingMenu()` (and chain it) like the example above with options for speed, how many to show, and the hide/show captions as well.  Take a peek and tell me which parts aren't quite right, easy to adjust from there.

Comment: Brilliant! looks spot on to me - thanks Nick. I'll test it out fully.

Comment: Nick it's answers like this one that make me love StackOverflow!